# How to fix app bar being covered by bezel?

Tags: android, flutter

I was just testing my app on Pixel3 XL emulator and noticed that the app bar is covered by the bezel. I thought the flutter framework handles this for app bar own its own. [image]

Is there a way to fix this? I also looked at SafeArea but that probably would make me to manage the app bar on all the pages of BottomNavigationBar.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a solution to your issue.

Comment: If an answer fixed your issue, remember to mark it as correct to help other users find the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue with the emulator, not Flutter. If you open Chrome on the emulator you will see that it's also covered by the notch. You can also drag from the notch and the notification's pane will be dragged down, even thought it shouldn't be possible.

You can fix this though. Open the Android settings, go to to the About phone section and tap on the Build Number 7 times, to enable developer mode. Once that's done, in Settings, go to the System section, open Advanced and go to Developer options. Tap the Display cutout option and select Tall cutout. This will adjust the OS to account for the notch.